# Open GoogleMaps app for navigation on android from website

Tags: javascript, android, angular, google-maps, mobile-website

I'm writing an angular 4 website that receives a list of lat/lng from the server and have a button that refers to Google Maps and constructs a route.

My desire is to refer the user to Google Maps app to navigate to those locations

I'm creating the url:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/dir/{origin lat},{origin lng}/{destination lat 1},{destination lng 1}/{destination lat 2},{destination lng 2}/{destination lat 3},{destination lng 3}/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e0
```

And then refers to the app by:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

On iPhones/iPads it works perfectly and the app is opened with the route,
On Desktop it refers to Google Maps site with the route.
However on android it opens the GoogleMaps app but without the route.

> (GoogleMaps app was installed on all iPohnes/iPads/android devices
>   testes)

How can I make the GoogleMaps app to open with the route also in android?

Answer (score 3):

**Directions** — request directions and launch Google Maps with the results:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters
```

> **Doc :** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gowthaman M,
had to reformat the url for android like so:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={origin lat},{origin lng}&destination={destination lat 1},{destination lng 1}&waypoints={destination lat 2},{destination lng 2}|{destination lat 3},{destination lng 3}&travelmode=driving
```

and now the android is opening the google maps app with the route in it.